# Word order in composite sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, subordinate-clause

I need to translate the following sentence into German:

> It depends on the weather, whether we will ski tomorrow or not.

using the following word-combination

> Es hängt ab von …

I think that the right translation would be

> Es hängt ab vom Wetter, Ski fahren wir morgen oder nicht.

I am confused with a second part, because as far as I know the predicate should take second place in a simple affirmative sentence.

And the second question: Is it a complex or compound sentence? I think that’s compound, but I’m not sure.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: There is nothing corresponding to _whether_ in your translation.

Comment: On another note: *von dem* always turns into *vom* and the correct German German version of *skiing* is *Ski fahren* although it is pronunced as if it were *Schi fahren*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that both in the English original and in the proper German sentence, the second part is, in fact, a subordinate clause that is introduced by *whether* in English — and that can luckily be translated directly into *ob* in German. So we can use the following as a starting point:

> Es hängt ab vom Wetter, ob …

However, *abhängen,* being a separable verb, would like to have its separable particle *ab* at the end of the corresponding sentence. So we reorder it to:

> Es hängt vom Wetter ab, ob …

Now let’s take a look at the *whether we will go skiing tomorrow or not* part. Our conjunction is *ob* — we already established that. *We* is the subject, our main verb is *to go skiing* which is in future tense. And then we have the *or not* at the end that we’ll come to later. Remember that future tense is rather uncommon in German so you were correct in assuming present tense instead. However, we have a subordinate clause, so the verb should be last.

> Es hängt vom Wetter ab, ob wir (subject) morgen (time) Ski fahren (finite verb).

And finally, we add the *or not,* translateable to *oder nicht* to the final construct. It can be seen as a shortened co-ordinated sentence (*oder* being a coordinating conjunction) and we can thus just put it at the end.

> Es hängt vom Wetter ab, ob wir morgen Ski fahren oder nicht.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Everything is very clear.